# Implementing syscalls under Miasm

Tags: python, x86-64, emulation, system-call

I'd like to use Miasm's DSE on a binary. This binary makes use of 2 syscalls: exit and ptrace. Miasm provides an [implementation of some syscalls](https://github.com/cea-sec/miasm/blob/master/miasm/os_dep/linux/syscall.py#L915), but unfortunately, not of those two.

So I tried to write them myself, using the above link as reference, like this:

```
def EXIT_syscall(jitter, linux_env):
    status, = jitter.syscall_args_systemv(1)
    print(f"Exit syscall, status {status}.")

    jitter.running = False


is_ptrace_first_call = True
def PTRACE_syscall(jitter, linux_env):
    request, pid, addr, data = jitter.syscall_args_systemv(4)
    print(request, pid, addr, data)

    global is_ptrace_first_call
    ptrace_return_value = -1

    if is_ptrace_first_call:
        ptrace_return_value = 0
        is_ptrace_first_call = False

    jitter.syscall_ret_systemv(ptrace_return_value)


syscall_callbacks_x86_64[0x3c] = EXIT_syscall
syscall_callbacks_x86_64[0x65] = PTRACE_syscall
# Syscalls are disabled by default
enable_syscall_handling(sb.jitter, LinuxEnvironment_x86_64(), syscall_callbacks_x86_64)
```

This exit syscall seems to work fine, but it is not the case for the ptrace one, and I don't know why since it pretty much looks like the other syscalls implemented in the link above.

The code above gives me a `miasm.analysis.dse.DriftException: Drift of exception_flags: 16 instead of 0`, which seems to correspond to a difference in the states of the concrete and symbolic execution.

How should I proceed ?

EDIT: I can also try something like:

```
def syscall_handler(jitter):
    print(f">>> Received Syscall {jitter.cpu.EAX}")

    if jitter.cpu.RAX == 0x3c:
        EXIT_syscall(jitter, None)
        return False
    elif jitter.cpu.RAX == 0x65:
        PTRACE_syscall(jitter, None)
        return True
    else:
        print(f"Unimplemented syscall ({jitter.cpu.RAX}), exiting. (RIP = {hex(jitter.cpu.RIP)})")
        exit()

sb.jitter.add_exception_handler(EXCEPT_SYSCALL, syscall_handler)
```

It seems to execute properly the ptrace syscall, however the execution doesn't seem to resume properly and the syscall 0 is called (because the ptrace one returned 0).